# Count records grouped by day that counted by interval

Tags: postgresql

Here is the query

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT current_date - serie AS date
    FROM generate_series(0, 365, 1) AS serie
), items AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM items
    WHERE created_at BETWEEN now() - interval '6 months' AND now()
)

SELECT dates.date, count(items)
FROM dates
LEFT OUTER JOIN items ON items.created_at::date = dates.date
GROUP BY dates.date
```

Everything works fine except one thing - I need to somehow replace `now()` with day in a row.
So for each day calculate items count with conditions based on that day.
Just can't reference it.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: with which day in in which row? please use cte alias and column names

Comment: @VaoTsun Sorry, `dates.date`

Comment: if you want to reference dates.date in items cte - you have to join it in it I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

smth like this?

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT current_date - serie AS date
    FROM generate_series(0, 365, 1) AS serie
)
SELECT dates.date, count(items)
FROM dates
LEFT OUTER JOIN items ON created_at BETWEEN dates.date- interval '6 months' AND dates.date
GROUP BY dates.date;
```

Comment: Came with same solution)
Please edit answer: remove `items.created_at::date = dates.date and` it will not count with this condition.

Answer (score 0):

I came to the following solution, which has the same result as Vao Tsun proposed:

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT current_date - serie AS date
    FROM generate_series(0, 365, 1) AS serie
), date_intervals AS (
    SELECT
      (dates.date - INTERVAL '6 months') AS start_date,
      dates.date                         AS end_date
    FROM dates
)

SELECT date_intervals.end_date, count(items)
FROM date_intervals
  LEFT OUTER JOIN items ON items.created_at BETWEEN date_intervals.start_date AND date_intervals.end_date
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
```